# How MVC web application works in java?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, web-applications

#### As we define view,controller,service and Dao layer in application then how data flow in between them.

e.g. suppose we add struts,spring,hibernate,etc. jars in project then how they work together?

Comment: This is too broad, you need to read up on the technologies you mention and then come back with any specific questions

Comment: Just refer this Link: [MVC Web Application in Java](http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/) Hope this helps you

Comment: **Thanks for your quick response @santhosh...it's more about spring docs.**
**I want to know how we can identify particular layer is doing his exact work or we can say that identification of each layer in application in very generic information.**

Comment: you want know in Model View Control which layer performs which function in detailed right...?

Answer (score 2):

The MVC pattern itself does not describe how should you implement your web application. What it describes is how your components should interact with each other in order to achieve a modular architecture with replaceable components.

The pattern is explained in details in Martin Fowler's [POEAA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420) and in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). More info about MVC can be found in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

**A simple example using Java, Spring and Hibernate**

In this case Spring MVC provides a pluggable framework where you can define your models , controllers and views without coupling them together too tightly (this is achieved through [IOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)/[DI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)).

The first thing to notice is the [DispatcherServlet](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) which is a regular servlet that serves as an entry point by handling all the incoming HTTP requests and routing them to their respective *controllers*. The appropriate controller is looked up by their mappings, eg. via [@RequestMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) annotations.

The controller's responsibility is to determine what actions should be performed as a response to the incoming request. This is usually done by checking headers, parameters, session info, path for information what the user wanted to do. Here is an extremely simple example:

```
if (session.getAttribute("authenticated") == false) {
    // we need to redirect to the login page
} else {
    // everything was fine, so we do some business logic in the model
    importantService.doSomethingReallyImportant(productOrder)
}
```

Then the control is passed to the *model* layer where business logic happens. This may include any operation that changes the model's state, like updating a password, registering a booking, clearing transactions, and so on. In web applications these operations often involve the use of a persistence API, eg. Hibernate.

```
public class ImportantService {
    public void doSomethingVeryImportant(final ProductOrder order) {
        // Here we define the business operation
        getCurrentBasket().add(order);

        // An additional pseudo-persistence operation
        getSession().update(order);
    }
}
```

In practice when the model has finished then control is returned to the *controller* which decides how to update the *view* (eg. redirecting the browser or just simply display a result page) where the user sees the result of his/her action.